# How to post comment in Linkedin using Hammock or RestSharp library?

Tags: c#, linkedin-api, restsharp, hammock

I could get all the posts and comments from LinkedIn but I am unable to add post comment

I tried with Hammock and RestSharp library still I get an error

> Could not parse message document or Unexpected file end null`or`Unauthentication scheme`

This is my code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string xmlContent = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<comment>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "<text>Check out</text>" + Environment.NewLine +
            "</comment>";
    byte[] dataBytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xmlContent);

    var credentials = new Hammock.Authentication.OAuth.OAuthCredentials
    {
        Type = OAuthType.AccessToken,
        SignatureMethod = OAuthSignatureMethod.HmacSha1,
        ParameterHandling = OAuthParameterHandling.HttpAuthorizationHeader,
        ConsumerKey = "*******",
        ConsumerSecret = "**********",
        Token = "********",
        TokenSecret = "*************",
        Version = "1.0"
    };

    // Am I declaring the URL in correct format
    var client = new Hammock.RestClient() { Authority = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/posts" };
    var request = new Hammock.RestRequest() { Path = "/{post-id}/comments", Method = Hammock.Web.WebMethod.Post, Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5), Credentials = credentials };
    request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    //request.AddParameter("application/json",json);
    //client.AddPostContent(dataBytes);
    request.AddPostContent(dataBytes);
    var response = client.Request(request);
    Response.Write(response.Content);
}
```

I get an error in the below format

```xml
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?>
<error>  
    <status>400</status>
    <timestamp>1374494502579</timestamp>
    <request-id>QM4MYPEKJJ</request-id>  
    <error-code>0</error-code>
    <message>Couldn't parse message document: error: Unexpected end of file after null</message>\n</error>
```